# "up to the waist" or "down to the waist"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I know that a pair of pants goes up to the waist, but what about a shirt? Does it go down to the waist? That's would make sense to me, as pants slide up in the body and a shirt slides down in the body, but languages are not always logical.

Comment: [correction: goes up to the waist||a shirt slides] I see no difference here with what this would be in Portuguese. subir até, descer até a cintura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you need to describe the length of a shirt by specifying which parts of the body are covered by it, then it definitely makes sense to say, "the shirt **goes** (or **comes**) **down to** the waist."

Examples:

> "This shirt only **goes down to** my waist, so it won't stay tucked
>   in."
>
> "Halter tops are not permitted. Shirts must **go all the way down** to the
>   waist."

Comment: This is a take-the-piss question, as the Brits might say. It's about up and down. If your pants to not go up to your waist, they might be hip huggers.

Comment: And what would the Brits mean, ... if they said that?

Answer (score 0):

It would be fine to say "goes down to [body part]," but a common phrase you will hear regarding the edges of clothing and see in product descriptions is that a garment "**falls at** [body part]."

So a shirt or jacket may "**fall at the hip**." (More likely than at the waist).

A skirt might "**fall at the knee**."

These jeans "**fall at the ankle**."